# Как объединить ячейки в выдаче?

Tags: mysql

Запрос:

```
select 
appointment_id, user_id, project_id, timesheet.date
from timesheet
left join appointment
on appointment_id = appointment.id
```

Получаем:

```css
thead tr {background-color: ActiveCaption; color: CaptionText;}
      th, td {vertical-align: top; font-family: "Tahoma", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 8pt; padding: 3px; }
      table, td {border: 1px solid silver;}
      table {border-collapse: collapse;}
      thead .col0 {width: 122px;}
      .col0 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col1 {width: 83px;}
      .col1 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col2 {width: 96px;}
      .col2 {text-align: right;}
      thead .col3 {width: 91px;}
```

```html
    <table caption="НеизвестнаяТаблица (3 rows)">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="col0">appointment_id</th>
          <th class="col1">user_id</th>
          <th class="col2">project_id</th>
          <th class="col3">date</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="col0">18</td>
          <td class="col1">1</td>
          <td class="col2">1</td>
          <td class="col3">2017-03-09</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col0">18</td>
          <td class="col1">1</td>
          <td class="col2">1</td>
          <td class="col3">2017-03-07</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col0">20</td>
          <td class="col1">1</td>
          <td class="col2">2</td>
          <td class="col3">2017-03-02</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Как объединить строку 1 и 2 чтобы дата была на еще одном столбце, какой функцией воспользоваться и как?

Comment: На сервере что? nodejs?

Comment: php, а какое это имеет значение?

Comment: А кто вам такую красивую таблицу нарисовал? Не php?

Comment: heidiSQL, результат запроса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте сгруппировать даты по первым полям

```
select appointment_id, user_id, project_id, GROUP_CONCAT(`date`)
from timesheet
group by appointment_id, user_id, project_id
```